# Porque não consigo sobrescrever uma Collection no Laravel utilizando a função values()?

Tags: laravel-4

Estou tentando sobrescrever minha Collection pra que ela receba ela mesma com as chaves reordenadas, o motivo é que estou dando um **forget()** e as vezes o elemento eliminado tem valor de chave igual a **0 (zero)**, e minha array de retorno acaba começando com o valor **1 (um)**, com o exemplo abaixo fica melhor de entender:

```
// Just for demonstration
$collection = collect([
    0 => ['nome' => 'Joao', 'idade' => 5],
    1 => ['nome' => 'Gabriel', 'idade' => 6]
]);

$collection->forget(0);

$collection = $collection->values();

return $collection->toArray();

/* Resultado retornado:
    [
             1 => ['nome' => 'Gabriel', 'idade' => 6]
    ]
*/

/* Resultado esperado:
    [
             0 => ['nome' => 'Gabriel', 'idade' => 6]
    ]
*/
```

Porém se eu substituir o nome da variável de retorno, ele retorna o resultado de maneira correta:

```
// Just for demonstration
$collection = collect([
    0 => ['nome' => 'Joao', 'idade' => 5],
    1 => ['nome' => 'Gabriel', 'idade' => 6]
]);

$collection->forget(0);

$values = $collection->values();

return $values->toArray();

/* Resultado retornado:
    [
             0 => ['nome' => 'Gabriel', 'idade' => 6]
    ]
*/
```

Comment: Não entendi bem?

Comment: Eu quero substituir o valor da $collection pela reordenada ($collection->values()), e o laravel só tá deixando se eu guardar essa collection com outro nome de variável, eu imagino que possa ser a versão do Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo que você disse é verdade e a solução é essa mesmo para o `Laravel` versão 4.2:

O método void `forget` remove um item da lista pela sua chave, o seu código é:

```
public function forget($key)
{
    unset($this->items[$key]);
}
```

e o método `values()` redefine as chaves e retorna a própria classe da coleção

```
public function values()
{
    $this->items = array_values($this->items);
    return $this; // retorna a instância atual
}
```

e na verdade se você fizer assim:

```
$collection->forget(0);
$collection->values(); 
// pode continuar usando aqui a mesma variavel
```

as chaves serão redefindas e o `array` vai ficar organizado.

<sup>***Ref.*** [Collection](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html)</sup>

***Observação:*** realmente há diferenças nas versões do `Laravel`, exemplo claro na versão do Laravel 5.7 o código é diferente e reproduz outra instância da classe `Collection`, código:

```
public function values()
{
    return new static(array_values($this->items));
}
```

de certo modo você tem razão porque vai depender mesmo da versão.

Comment: muito obrigado, isso esclareceu minhas dúvidas